# Problems insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, parent-child, foreign-key-relationship

I made a database recipes, it consists of; recipe's name, ID number, ingredients, preperation, image etc. 
After that I made a php and html script so I can search in the databese (for example: dinner with preperation time less than 45 min.). 
No I'm working on a php script to insert new recipes. I can insert $sql1. But when I try to insert $sql2 it says: 
Could not enter data retval 2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`recepten`.`benodigdheid`, CONSTRAINT `benodigdheid_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `gerecht` (`ID`))
I understand the problem is in the child/parent relation and the foreign key, but I can't find the problem. Do you first have to add data in 'Ingredient'? Or first in 'Gerecht'?
Below I wrote down part of the script, I can give more if required.

PHP script to insert new recipe:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO Gerecht ( gerechtnaam, personen, categorie, bereidingstijd, bereidingswijze, plaatje)
VALUES ('$gerechtnaam','$personen','$categorie','$bereidingstijd','$bereidingswijze','$plaatje')";
$sql2="INSERT INTO Benodigdheid (benodigdheden)
VALUES ('$benodigdheden')";
$sql3="INSERT INTO Product (ingredientnaam, eenheidnaam)
VALUES ('$ingredientnaam1', '$eenheid1')";
$sql4="INSERT INTO Ingredient (ingredientnaam, hoeveelheid)
VALUES ('$ingredientnaam1', '$hoeveelheid1')";

$retval1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql4 );
if(! $retval1 )
{
  die('Could not enter data retval 1: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "Entered data retval1 successfully\n";

$retval2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql2 );
if(! $retval3 )
{
  die('Could not enter data retval 2: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "Entered data retval2 successfully\n";
```

Create script database:

```
  CREATE TABLE Gerecht 
(ID      INT(3)   AUTO_INCREMENT     NOT NULL,
 gerechtnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL,
 personen  NUMERIC(2)    NOT NULL,
 categorie  VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
 bereidingstijd  NUMERIC(3)     NOT NULL,
 bereidingswijze   TEXT   NOT NULL,
 plaatje      VARCHAR(250)      NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Benodigdheid
(ID    INT(3)    NOT NULL,
 benodigdheden     VARCHAR(35)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID, benodigdheden), 
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Eenheid
(eenheidnaam     VARCHAR(12)    NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (eenheidnaam)
);

CREATE TABLE Product
(ingredientnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL,
 eenheidnaam     VARCHAR(12),
 PRIMARY KEY (ingredientnaam),
 FOREIGN KEY (eenheidnaam) REFERENCES Eenheid (eenheidnaam)
);

CREATE TABLE Ingredient
(ID    INT(3)       NOT NULL,
 ingredientnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL,
 hoeveelheid      NUMERIC(4)    NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ID, ingredientnaam),
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID),
 FOREIGN KEY (ingredientnaam) REFERENCES Product (ingredientnaam)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not trying to insert the ID of the `Gerecht` when inserting into  `Benodigheid`.  You MUST insert this value as well since there is a referential integrity constraint on the table.  After your first SQL insert, you need to read out the id of the last inserted `Gerecht` record (perhaps by using `mysqli_insert_id()` and then add that id value in the insert to `Benodigheid` table.  So `$sql2` should look like this:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO Benodigdheid (ID, benodigdheden)
       VALUES ($id_from_sql1, '$benodigdheden')";
```

Your `Benodigdheid` table also seems flawed in that it should have its own autoincrement primary key as well as the foreign key referencing `Gerecht`.  Though in looking at what you are doing, it seems like there is 1 to 1 relationship between `Gerecht` and `Benodigheid`, so I actually don't know why you wouldn't just have `benogdigheid` as a column on `Gerecht` if this is your intent.

I generally looking over your schema, it would seem clear that you need to get in the practice of adding autoincrement primary keys to your tables (which is commonly done for most all relational DB tables).  You are going to have the same problem on your `ingredient` tables

Comment: Thanks Mike. 'Benodigdheid' are kitchen supplies. Somethimes a recipe needs more than one kitchen supply, that's the reason why I made an extra table. One dish only needs one ID. So when I add a new recipe it needs to make one ID (auto increment) and uses that ID for the other tables. But I think with the script you gave me that will work.

Comment: @sophie  A reasonable schema for your `Benodigheid` table would have an autoincrementing primary key, a foreign like `berecht_id` which references ID in `Gerecht`, and then your data field.  So three columns, not two.

Comment: I changed it into:

CREATE TABLE Benodigdheid
(IDbenodigdheid    INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT   NOT NULL,
 ID    INT(3)     NOT NULL,
 benodigdheden     VARCHAR(35)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (IDbenodigdheid, benodigdheden), 
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID)
);
But I still get the same error.

Comment: @sophie You still need to insert the value for Gerecht ID when creating a record in Benodigdheid.

Comment: Doesn't it come in Benodigdheid with the reference key? How can I insert Gerecht ID into Benodigdheid?

Comment: @sophie Read my answer above.

Comment: It says undefined varable id_from_sql1, because I didn't define it. I want to have it ganerated automaticaly. How do I have to define id_from_sql1?

Comment: @sophie I was using that variable name as an example. You need to use `mysqli_insert_id()` after the first query to get the id of the record that was inserted. That is what should be used where I called the variable `$id_from_sql1`

Comment: Thanks Mike. Now I have:
$sql1="INSERT INTO Gerecht ( gerechtnaam, personen, categorie, bereidingstijd, bereidingswijze, plaatje)
VALUES ('$gerechtnaam','$personen','$categorie','$bereidingstijd','$bereidingswijze','$plaatje')";
$sql2="INSERT INTO Benodigdheid (ID, benodigdheden)
VALUES (mysql_insert_id(), '$benodigdheden')";

It get:
Could not enter data retval 2: FUNCTION recepten.mysql_insert_id does not exist
And when I just echo mysql_insert_id() I get 0. So that means the previous operation does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT ID. What's wrong?

Comment: @sophie `mysqli_insert_id()` is a PHP function.  Read the documentation on its usage.  Though you could optionally use the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the fashion you are currently trying to use `mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: Now I have the same problem, with the table to add ingredients. I made an extra ID like I did with Benodigdheid, but it doesn't help. Query: $sql4="INSERT INTO Ingredient (ID, ingredientnaam, hoeveelheid)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$ingredientnaam1', '$hoeveelheid1')"; Create file: CREATE TABLE Ingredient
(IDingredient    INT(3)  AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
 ID    INT(3)       NOT NULL,
 ingredientnaam     VARCHAR(35)    NOT NULL, 
 hoeveelheid      NUMERIC(4)    NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (IDingredient, ingredientnaam),
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID)
);

Comment: @sophie First, you shouldn;t call you foreign key just `ID` this is very confusing. It should be like `GerechtId` or something meaningful.  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for your query sql4 will use the primary key id generated on the LAST insert (in this case sql3).  If that is not the id you are trying to insert in sql4, then you will need to store the inserted id value you want to use here (`GerechtID`) into a variable in PHP.  This gets back to the original suggestion of using `mysqli_insert_id()` after sql1, so you have this value available later on.

Comment: Now I have $IDGerecht=mysql_insert_id(); after sql1. Then I use $IDGerecht in sql2 en sql4. But then I get the old error (Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails). ?? And I found the other problem for 'Ingredient'; I use ingredientnaam as part of the primary key (together with IDGerecht) AND as foreign key (I left that part in the comment). I need an primary key consisting off two parts (just IDGerecht isn't enough). But I also have to reference to my table Product (ingredientnaam is the linking column). Do I need an extra column to solve this problem?

Comment: @sophie I don't know.  At this point I don;t have a good feel for what your DB schema and code are now changed to look like.  I would suggest opening a new question.

Comment: I opened a new question: Problems with insert data in database

Answer (score 0):

You have set a constraint on the table Benodigdheid from its key ID to the primary key ID in Gerecht. You need a separate foreign key. You can't have the primary key and the foreign key be the same column.
I don't understand the words so I don't know exactly what fits to what, but that constraint is a problem and gives you the error.

Comment: You actually CAN technically have primary and foreign key on the same column, it just probably points to a bad schema as I can't think of a case where this would actually make sense to do.

Comment: just to clarify, `benodigdheid = requisite` and `gerecht = dish`

Comment: Thanks broch for your answer. First of all: Benodigdheid = kitchen supply, Gerecht = dish, gerechtnaam = dishname, Eenheid=unit. The ID from Gerecht has to be the same as the ID in Benodigdheid (that how you know wich kitchen supply you need for wich dish). So the reference key has to be ID. And I think I also can't change the primary key. So what do you suggest?

Comment: If one dish can have more kitchen supplies it is a one to many relationship. Your gerecht table is fine but your benodigdheid should be something like this: 

| ID  (int) | name (varchar(35)) |  fkGerecht(int) |

The ID is then unique for all entries in Benodigdheid but fkGerecht (the foreign key) points to the ID of the Gerecht table and you can make a contraint like: FOREIGN KEY (fkGerecht) REFERENCES GERECHT(ID)

Comment: I switched it into:

CREATE TABLE Benodigdheid
(IDbenodigdheid    INT(3) AUTO_INCREMENT   NOT NULL,
 ID    INT(3)     NOT NULL,
 benodigdheden     VARCHAR(35)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (IDbenodigdheid, benodigdheden), 
 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Gerecht (ID)
);
But I still get the same error.